# UWP Concurrent Threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, uwp, windows-10

So I am converting a library to UWP that creates multiple threads that run concurrently and then grabs all the data from all of them at the end. I have been looking in to `await` and `async` as well as `Task`. I believe I am going to make a class that returns a `Task<myType>` with the data I need.

I am wondering if there is a way inside UWP to let all of these instances of the function run concurrently instead of using `await` and waiting for each individual instance to finish before starting the next.

Thanks so much!

Comment: `Task.Run`, `Task.WhenAll`.

Comment: `Task` has some helper methods for this, `Task.AwaitAll` for example. See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270695(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Perhaps `Parallel.For` is easier

Comment: Both solutions look great! I will try out both and see which works!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One approach is to wrap each task into a `Task`, run them as soon as they are created, and then wait on all of them at the end.

Some sample code:

```
var tasks = new List<Task>();

var task1 = Task.Run(() => FetchData1());
tasks.Add(task1);

var task2 = Task.Run(() => FetchData2());
tasks.Add(task2);

Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
```

Comment: Glad I could help. By the way, this is not only limited to UWP. You can use the same strategy in your other C# projects as well.

Comment: I'd replace Task.Factory.StartNew with Task.Run.

Comment: That is what I ended up doing anyways :)